# Symfony 4 Traditional Login Form and TwigTemplates Error

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony

i got a problem when I try to make a Login Form, I followed this tutorial

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

I made my routes like that

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::login

    login:
        path: /
        controller: App\Controller\SecurityConfirmController::index
```

Where SecurityController load my form (login.html.twig) and SecurityConfirmController try to display the username and the password get by the request (logged.html.twig).

And when I click on the submit button the public/index.php send me to the public/login.php but the ErrorLog in SecurityConfirmController::index is never display and the templates of the login.php stay the same as the index.php

(I don't extends the login.html.twig in my base.html.twig, and I call the name login.html.twig only in the SecurityController)

Do you know how to fix it ? thanks !

**src/Controller/SecurityController.php**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;


class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */

    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
    {
        error_log(".Login.");

    // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }

}
```

**src/Controller/SecurityConfirmController.php**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;



class SecurityConfirmController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */

    public function index(EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils) 
    {

        error_log(".OMG.");
        $username = $request->get('_username');
        $password = $request->get('_password');

        return $this->render('security/logged.html.twig', array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
        ));
    }

}
```

**templates/security/login.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/login.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">


        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>


        {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        <form action="login.php" method="post" class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

            <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control" required autofocus/>

            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password"  class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required/>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>

            {#
                If you want to control the URL the user
                is redirected to on success (more details below)
                <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
                #}

            <button type="submit">login</button>
        </form>


    </div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

**templates/security/logged.html.twig**

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    <p> {{ username }} <p> <br>
    <p> {{ password }} <p> <br> 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In your routes, looks like you are trying t have path: / point to two different actions?

Comment: I thought that "/" was /public btw when i try to write /index.php i got an error

Comment: Hmmm.  Might need to review [routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html).  Almost seems like you are trying to mix yaml and annotations which seldom ends well.  But more relevant, consider getting the example in your link working first before adding things like SecurityConfirmController.   Really not sure what it is that you are trying to confirm.

Comment: I didn't enable the annotations, it was in the exemple i just copy/past, But you say true i shouldn't blend them together. I erased the annotations and it's quite better, the button works now ! Thank's